# Selenium 'Element cannot be scrolled into view' after scrolling element into view with JavaScript

Tags: c#, selenium

I am scrolling an element into view via JavaScript, but when trying to click on that element an exception is being raised which says the element cannot be scrolled into view.  When I look at the browser, it has been successfully scrolled into view.

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(WaitTimeout));
var nextPageButton = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(NextPageButtonSelector));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", nextPageButton);
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style.width = '100%';", nextPageButton);
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style.height = '100%';", nextPageButton);
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style.position = 'fixed';", nextPageButton);
nextPageButton.Click();
```

P.S. Neither javascript element.click() or the Actions class worked.

Comment: first scroll down, then wait to be clickable

Comment: @Infern0 I just tried your idea and it didn't work.  Same exception when scrolling into view before the wait.Until call.

Answer (score 1):

Solved my own question by adding a Thread.Sleep call before clicking.  I know this is not recommended, but it is literally the only solution i've been able to find.  :(

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(WaitTimeout));
var nextPageButton = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(NextPageButtonSelector));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", nextPageButton);
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style.width = '100%';", nextPageButton);
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style.height = '100%';", nextPageButton);
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style.position = 'fixed';", nextPageButton);
Thread.Sleep(500);
nextPageButton.Click();
```

Comment: Why are you manipulating css styles within a e2e test? This can't be good practice!
Users won't do that - i guess.

Comment: @nilsK I am scraping 3rd party sites for public proxy lists.  Sometimes, the next page button is obscured slightly by other elements.  (Easily clickable by me manually in the browser, but Selenium throws a fit by the slightest imperceptible overlap) Changing the CSS fixed that problem.